# Define aspect ratio for iPhone app running iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, iphone-4

My App is iPhone only and is optimized for all Devices running iOS 11... so that does not include iPhone4 Screen-Sizes.
Now I also don't support the iPad and now if you run my app there, it will be the iPhone version scaled up. The problem is that the iPad chooses the iPhone 4 Aspect-Ratio...

Is there a simple way to tell iOS not to do that?

Comment: If your app isn't Universal, then it will run on an iPad at iPhone 4 resolution.  I suggest you make your app Universal and increase your potential market to iPad owners.

Comment: Yes, but i was hoping for a quicker solution for now... thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't do that, unfortunately. 
The way I fixed it (my problem was that the screens weren't made for such a small size. so, the layout looked terrible) was using [AssistantKit](https://github.com/anatoliyv/AssistantKit) to determine the device type:

```
    let device = Device.type

        switch device {
        case .phone:      print("iPhone")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "iphoneVC") as! LoginViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        case .pad:        print("iPad");
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPad", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ipadVC") as! LoginViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        case .pod:        print("iPod")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPad", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ipadVC") as! LoginViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        case .simulator:  print("Simulator")
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "iphoneVC") as! LoginViewController

// this is used to test in the Sim, this kit can't determine device type from the Sim        
//            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "iPad", bundle: nil)
//            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ipadVC") as! LoginViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        default:          print("Unknown")
        }
```

if You only want to specifically check for a specific device type (works with sim):

```
Device.isPhone     // true for iPhones even if it's Simulator
Device.isPhoneX    // true for iPhoneX even if it's Simulator
Device.isPad       // true for iPads even if it's Simulator
Device.isPadPro    // true for iPad Pros even if it's Simulator
Device.isPod       // true for iPods
Device.isSimulator // true for Simulators
```

You could also use this Kit to switch storyboard/views based on screen size or specific device:
Screen size:

```
let screen = Device.screen

switch screen {
case .inches_3_5:  print("3.5 inches")
case .inches_4_0:  print("4.0 inches")
case .inches_4_7:  print("4.7 inches")
case .inches_5_5:  print("5.5 inches")
case .inches_7_9:  print("7.9 inches")
case .inches_9_7:  print("9.7 inches")
case .inches_12_9: print("12.9 inches")
default:           print("Other display")
}
```

Device version:

```
let version = Device.version

switch version {
case .phone4:       print("iPhone 4")
case .phone4S:      print("iPhone 4S")
case .phone5:       print("iPhone 5")
case .phone5C:      print("iPhone 5C")
case .phone5S:      print("iPhone 5S")
case .phone6:       print("iPhone 6")
case .phone6S:      print("iPhone 6S")
case .phone6Plus:   print("iPhone 6 Plus")
case .phone6SPlus:  print("iPhone 6 S Plus")

case .pad1:         print("iPad 1")
case .pad2:         print("iPad 2")
case .pad3:         print("iPad 3")
case .pad4:         print("iPad 4")
case .padAir:       print("iPad Air")
case .padAir2:      print("iPad Air 2")
case .padMini:      print("iPad Mini")
case .padMini2:     print("iPad Mini 2")
case .padMini3:     print("iPad Mini 3")
case .padMini4:     print("iPad Mini 4")
case .padPro:       print("iPad Pro")

case .podTouch1:    print("iPod 1")
case .podTouch2:    print("iPod 2")
case .podTouch3:    print("iPod 3")
case .podTouch4:    print("iPod 4")
case .podTouch5:    print("iPod 5")
case .podTouch6:    print("iPod 6")

case .simulator:    print("Simulator")

default:            print("Unknown device")
}
```

Source:  [AssistantKit](https://github.com/anatoliyv/AssistantKit)